# Using metadata to get a reference to the class calling a certain method

Tags: c#

When using INotifyPropertyChanged it is possible to do something like this to get the name of the property where the method invoking the event was called.

```
 public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(new object(), new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));

        }

    }
```

Is there some other type of attribute to use to also get a reference to the class that contains that property? I want to be able to call `RaisePropertyChanged()` from any property from any of my viewmodel classes. All my viewmodel classes derive from a base so I'm thinking I can do something like this.

```
 public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "", [CallerClassRef] VmBase base = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(base, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword to access the current class reference is called `this`:

```
public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

This will work no matter how many times you derive this class, `this` is always the instance this function was called on.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Fody - PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) add in. It helps you to inject INotifyPropertyChanged implementation to IL code.

Source code :

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class Person 
{        
    public string GivenNames { get; set; }
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", GivenNames, FamilyName);
        }
    }
}
```

When compiled

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    string givenNames;
    public string GivenNames
    {
        get { return givenNames; }
        set
        {
            if (value != givenNames)
            {
                givenNames = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("GivenNames");
                OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
            }
        }
    }

    string familyName;
    public string FamilyName
    {
        get { return familyName; }
        set 
        {
            if (value != familyName)
            {
                familyName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FamilyName");
                OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
            }
        }
    }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", GivenNames, FamilyName);
        }
    }

    public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChanged != null)
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Source code copied from : https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged